# how to change db value value using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

i want to change some db value using javascript i have list of orders i select them and and want to change some of ids but it is not working need help here is my screen shot [image: If my check box is checked then click change ot button that's opens a model which gives select option (list of users)]

but when i select user and proceed to change user it doesnot work here is popup ss [image: on click change ordertaker nothing happened if i paas confirm-btn then it works but it doesnot paas value to controller]

here is my code

here is each buttons checkbox and model code
action Button (Change ot)

```
<button type="button" @if(Auth::user()->role < 3) data-toggle="modal" data-target="#orderchange-unapprove-popup" @else onclick="document.getElementById('multiple-approve').submit()" @endif class="btn btn-success btn-sm app-mult">Change Ot</button>
```

check box

```
<label class="btn btn-default btn-sm check-show-all-orders">
                <input type="checkbox" name="confirm-to[]" value="{{ $order->id }}" class="approve-to" />
              </label>
```

model

```
<div class="modal fade" id="orderchange-unapprove-popup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Directly Send To Pending Invoice ? <small></small></h5>
        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>
            Do you want to send selected orders to pending invoices ?
        </p>
        <div class="form-group">
           <select name="ot_id" required class="form-control" id="ot_id_popup_confirm">
            <option value="" disabled value="" selected>Please Select Ordetaker to Assign order</option>
            @if(!empty($ortaker))
              @foreach($ortaker as $item)
                <option value="{{$item->id}}">{{ $item->name }}</option>
              @endforeach
            @endif
        </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary confirm-ord">Ordertaker Confirm</button>
        </div>
      
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

passing id hiddenly

```
<form style="display: none" method="post" action="{{ route('approve.order.multiple') }}" id="multiple-approve">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    
    <!--Question does this cause issue?-->
    <input type="hidden" name="send_to_unapprove" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="selected_seller" value="{{ Auth::id() }}" id="input-seller">
    <input type="hidden" name="ot_id" value="{{ Auth::id() }}" id="input-ot">
</form>
```

java script

```
$(document).on('change', "select#ot_id_popup_confirm", function(e){
    $("#multiple-approve #input-ot").val($(this).val());
  });
```

controller code

```
 public function confirmOrder($id, $sendToUnapprove = true, $selectedSeller = null , $selectedOrdertaker = null){

        if(Auth::user()->role <= 3 && $sendToUnapprove != true &&  
            $selectedSeller == null && $selectedOrdertaker != null){
            Order::where('id' , $id)->update(['user_id' => $selectedOrdertaker, 'ot_id' => $selectedOrdertaker]);

        }
        else if(Auth::user()->role <= 3 && $sendToUnapprove != true){
            Order::where('id' , $id)->update(['is_confirmed_seller' => Auth::id(), 'selected_seller' => $selectedSeller]);

        }
}
```

there selected ordertaker pass the function to upper function to update data but it oesnot work

```
public function confirmOrderMult(Request $request){
        
        $productData = $request->all();
        $selectedSeller = ($request->selected_seller > 0) ? $request->selected_seller : Auth::id();
        $selectedOrdertaker = ($request->ot_id > 0) ? $request->ot_id : Auth::id();
        if($productData['confirm-to']!=null){
            $confirmed_orders=$productData['confirm-to'];
            foreach($confirmed_orders as $ap){
                $sendToUnapprove = $request->send_to_unapprove ? true : false;
                $this->confirmOrder($ap, $sendToUnapprove, $selectedSeller, 
                    $selectedOrdertaker);
            }
            return Common::Message("Order" , 4);
        }
        else{
            $approved_orders=$productData['approve-to'];
            foreach($approved_orders as $ap){
                $this->approveOrder($ap);
            }
            return Common::Message("Order" , 4);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since you use jQuery you might wanna look at $.ajax() to call your API which will update your DB at the server.

Comment: Hi , `Change ot` is submitting your form as you have `onclick=""` . But , till then you have not assign  value to `input-ot` according to your code this value gets assign when you change selectbox inside modal..but before that only your form gets submitted.Also, what happens when you click on `Ordertaker Confirm` ?